# OnTouchListener in Android

Tags: android

How can I get the X and Y Yadoes when the user touchs the screen at first and when you remove the finger from the screen. (First and coastal X coordinates when the user removes his finger as well as coordinates y)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override onTouchEvent like below. It will return X,Y.

```
  Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int yourX = (int)event.getX();
        int yourY = (int)event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: when i use method ACTION_MOVE it will give me the new X and y's coasts after the moving after the user removes his finger from the screen?

Comment: Thank you❤. But how can i get the old x,y , Where the touch event originated from. Please help me